# Windows Paste from Word (RTF) contains unavailable font name

Tags: windows, fonts, ms-word, clipboard, rtf

I have a Word document with some Cyrillic text.  If I place the cursor in the text, I can see that it is using a font called "Adobe Heiti Std R" for this text.  If I copy this text and paste it into my application's Rich-Text control in Windows 7, when I intercept the RTF coming in from the paste, I can see that there is an entry in the font table of the RTF string:

{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset204 Adobe Heiti Std R Cyr;}

Word has set the font name for that text to "Adobe Heiti Std R Cyr" in the RTF it built for the paste.  Clearly, Word has added the " Cyr" to the end to denote a Cyrillic font.

When I ask Windows to enumerate the font families, I can see the "Adobe Heiti Std R" font, but there isn't an "Adobe Heiti Std R Cyr" font on my system.  The problem is, if I try to locate the "...Cyr" font via the Windows font enumerator, I'm not going to find it.

I'm wondering if there is a standard way this " Cyr" suffix is used -- and if there are other suffixes I need to be aware of when pasting from Word.  I'm thinking that if there is a standard for these, it would let me detect it, set the proper character set for that language and select the proper font.  So far I can't find anything helpful.  Am I right about this suffix?  And if so, where is this documented?

Comment: I read through the RTF 1.9.1 spec, but nowhere does it explain that script suffix. It's plain old not supposed to be there, near as I can figure. The explanation of `\fname` points out that fonts can indicate their script, but then cites `Arial` as untagged, and `Arial (Cyrillic)` as tagged example, which is not what you're seeing, and the spec claims "this control word is used by WordPad. Word ignores this control word (and never creates it)." so that doesn't really help us, since there is no `\fname` in your RTF string...